# iPhone animated splash screen, hiding behind status pane

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So I'd like to have a full screen splash (320x480 - without status pane and same image as Default.png) animate off screen to the left after a short delay. I can create the splash and the animation ok, the only problem is that the status pane from the underlying view controller appears over the top of the splash screen. How can I animate a full screen splash so that the underlying root view controller (which has a status pane) is revealed as the animation progresses, without it's status pane appearing over the splash screen.

I use the info.plist flag to initially hide the status pane, but I want the status pane to be visible only on the underlying view as the splash moves off screen, but not appear over the top of the splash itself.

I don't want to hide the underlying status pane and show it again at the end of the animation, I'd just like it to be revealed gradually with the rest of the main view.

I hope this all makes sense.

Thanks
2J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the animated splash view controller to the status window and then fade it out. I don't believe the view is clipped, if it is you may be out of luck. It can be accessed like this example.

```
UIWindow *statusWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

    statusWindow.hidden = NO;
    statusWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1;
    UIView *mask = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    mask.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [statusWindow addSubview:mask];

    [statusWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:5 options:nil animations:^{
        statusWindow.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        [statusWindow removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

This way the status bar will be hidden. The only problem is that you are going to need to track orientation changes and adjust the mask manually considering it is a UIWindow that is above the status bar window.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Although I thought that maybe a second UIWindow was a possible solution here, I found the following in the Apple iOS programming guide...  UIWindow object
A UIWindow object coordinates the presentation of one or more views on a screen. Most apps have only one window, which presents content on the main screen, but apps may have an additional window for content displayed on an external display.
To change the content of your app, you use a view controller to change the views displayed in the corresponding window. You never replace the window itself.

Comment: It doesn't say you can't. Just suggests not to.

Comment: The latest programming guide stipulates - "You never replace the window itself". This is probably stronger than 'suggesting' that you don't do it. App is for an important client so can't take any risks regarding rejection. I've marked the answer as working though, but really would like to find a solution that doesn't bend the approval rules in any way. - Thanks :)

Comment: You're not really replacing the window though, you're just adding another one. I have used this method in production code and it has been approved no problem. I think what Apple is trying to prevent is exactly what they are saying, replacing the window. I have tried replacing the window in a different app and the results are very sloppy. I can understand why they would want to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using a very basic splash screen.  The following code should be added at the end of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in the application delegate.

```
// create splash screen
splashView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
splashView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

// adding views to window
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
[self.window addSubview:splashView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

// animate splash screen
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeSplashView:)];
[splashView setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: @ David. Thanks for the supplied suggestion, but it doesn't actually hide the status pane of the rootController view. As soon as the splash screen appears, the status pane appears over the top of it, before the animation has even begun.